# Python, регулярные выражения. Удалить из строки блоки в скобках

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка из случаных символов, в произвольных местах расположены группы символов в скобках

```
string = fdhjkds(fd12)fdsjf(4234)fdsklv;ad(fffds)gfd,.d
```

каким регулярным выражением можно удалить все участки со скобками.

операция

```
string = re.sub(r'\(.+\)', '', string)
```

удаляет участок от первой до последней скобки, игнорируя вложенные скобки,

```
(fd12)fdsjf(4234)fdsklv;ad(fffds)
```

и возвращает некорректный результат

```
fdhjkdsgfd,.d
```

как задать регулярку, чтобы добиться нужного результата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = re.sub(r'\([^\)]+\)', '', string)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Просто исключить символ кавычки, не догадался, все просто